# TypeError: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

Tags: python, json

I'm newbie to python and I would like to extract hero names of dota2 from a json file on https://github.com/kronusme/dota2-api/blob/master/data/heroes.json

and got dump() missig 'fp'

Can anyone help me, please?

I tried

```
import json 
import requests

source = requests.get('https://github.com/kronusme/dota2-api/blob/master/data/heroes.json')
hero = json.dump(source)
```

and expected I can save the json files as string or text

Comment: `Response` has a `json()` message that will directly parse a json response. You're going to struggle to get anything from that url though, it returns html. You might want `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kronusme/dota2-api/master/data/heroes.json` instead. Click the raw link on the github page to find the useful url.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still got the same error message on json.dump...

Comment: You don't need `json.dump()`. `src = requests.get('...'); src.json()` will return the parsed json object. `dump` converts a python object into JSON, even if you were parsing the response yourself, you'd need `load`. Something like `src = requests.get('...'); json.loads(src.text)`

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because you need to specify the filename/filepath to which the content should be written.
If you can get you content into a python type (e.g a list or string or something like that), then you can do

```
with open("filename.json", "w") as f:
   json.dump(source, f)
```

That will put the content of your source variable into the json file. Then you can do this to read the content from the json file back into python format:

```
with open("filename.json", "r") as f:
       data = json.load(f)
```

Something to look out for is to ensure that you use *json.dump* not json.dumps. The first one writes data to a file and the second one is used to serialise python data to json format.